# Реализация методов в LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

Всем добрый вечер. Прошу помощи в таком вопросе: у меня есть LinkedList с реализованными в нем методами, не получается реализовать 3 метода: public boolean remove(int index) - удаление элемента по индексу;  public boolean removeElement(int element) - удаление самого элемента и public void set(int index, int element) - замена элемента. Помогите кто чем может, заранее благодарен.

```
package com.inguarus;

public class IntLinkedList extends BaseList implements IntList {

    private Node first;
    private Node last;

    private static class Node {
        int element;
        Node next;
        Node previous;

        public Node(int element) {
            this.element = element;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int element) {
        Node newNode = new Node(element);
        if (first == null) {
            newNode.next = null;
            newNode.previous = null;
            first = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        } else {
            last.next = newNode;
            newNode.previous = last;
            last = newNode;
        }
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, int element) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        Node newNode = new Node(element);
        if (index == 0) {
            add(element);
        }
        if (index == size) {
            last.next = newNode;
            last = newNode;
        }
        Node oldNode = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            oldNode = oldNode.next;
        }
        Node oldPrevious = oldNode.previous;
        oldPrevious.next = newNode;
        oldNode.previous = newNode;

        newNode.previous = oldPrevious;
        newNode.next = oldNode;
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        first = null;
        last = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(int element) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (get(i) == element) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int get(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        Node result = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            result = result.next;
        }

        return result.element;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeElement(int element) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int index, int element) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовал нужные мне методы с помощью дополнительных методов:

```
public boolean remove(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > size - 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (index == 0) {
        first = first.next;
    } else {
        Node node = findNodeBeforeByIndex(index);
        Node tmp = findByIndex(index);
        node.next = tmp.next;
    }
    size--;
    return false;
}
public boolean removeElement(int element) {

    if (size == 0) {
        return false;
    } else if (size == 1) {
        first = null;
        last = null;
        size = 0;
        return true;
    }

    Node nodeBefore = findNodeBefore(element);

    if (nodeBefore.element == 0) {
        first = first.next;
        size--;
        return true;
    } else if (nodeBefore != null) {
        if (last.element == element) {
            nodeBefore.next = null;
            last = nodeBefore;
        } else {
            nodeBefore.next = nodeBefore.next.next;
        }
        size--;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private Node findByIndex(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > size - 1) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    int tmpIndex = 0;
    if (first == null) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    if (index == 0) {
        return first;
    }

    Node node = first;
    while (node.next != null) {
        node = node.next;
        tmpIndex++;
        if (tmpIndex == index) {
            return node;
        }
    }
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
}
private Node findNodeBefore(int value) {
    if (first.element == value) {
        return new Node();
    }

    Node node = first;
    while (node.next != null) {
        if (node.next.element == value) {
            return node;
        }
        node = node.next;
    }
    return null;
}

private Node findNodeBeforeByIndex(int index) {
    if (index <= 0 || index > size - 1) {
        return null;
    }

    int count = 0;
    Node node = first;
    while (node.next != null) {
        if (count == index - 1) {
            return node;
        }
        count++;
        node = node.next;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: супер круто! > МОЙ ПЕРЕПОД ПО ПРОГРАММИРОВАНИЮ